# My macOss app takes a long time to respond in the form and calculations

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I'm relatively new to SwiftUI and am currently working on developing an application that we intend to use within our company.

The application is designed to calculate prices for our customers. While all functionalities are working as expected, I am experiencing significant lag in the app's responsiveness.

For instance, when I click on a picker, it sometimes takes a few seconds for it to open. The same delay occurs when I click the following button:

```
Button(action: {
    self.selectedMargin = margin
}) {
    Text("\(margin)%")
        .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 17))
}
```

Though I understand that the code could likely be more efficient and concise, I find it surprising that the app is so slow, considering it only consists of 450 lines of code and a few formulas. For comparison, we also have these calculations in Excel, and there they work almost instantly.

I would greatly appreciate any tips you can offer to improve the app's responsiveness.

```
import SwiftUI
import AppKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedBox9m3 = 0
    @State private var selectedBox13m3 = 0
    @State private var selectedBox15m3 = 0
    @State private var selectedHuurTermijn = 0.0
    @State private var selectedHuurTermijnIndex = 0
    @State private var kilometersHeen = 0
    @State private var kilometersTerug = 0
    @State private var selectedTijdHeen = 0
    @State private var selectedTijdTerug = 0
    @State private var selectedWachtTijdHeen = 0
    @State private var selectedWachtTijdTerug = 0
    @State private var selectedTTTijdHeen = 0
    @State private var selectedTTTijdTerug = 0

    let boxCounts = Array(0...10)
    let kilometerCounts = Array(stride(from: 0, to: 500, by: 5))
    let huurTermijnen = Array(stride(from: 0.0, to: 100.5, by: 0.5))
    
    // Kosten
    @State private var storageCost: Double = 0
    @State private var kilometerCost: Double = 0
    @State private var timeCost: Double = 0
    @State private var totalCost: Double = 0
    @State private var totalCostTT: Double = 0
    @State private var geselecteerdeMarge: Int = 0
    
    //Omzet
    @State private var huurOmzet: Double = 0
    @State private var transportkostenHeenOmzet: Double = 0
    @State private var transportkostenTerugOmzet: Double = 0
    @State private var ttOmzetHeen: Double = 0
    @State private var ttOmzetTerug: Double = 0
    @State private var totalOmzetEx: Double = 0
    @State private var totalOmzetIncl: Double = 0

    
    // Kosten per eenheid (deze kunnen later worden aangepast)
    let RentcostPerBox = 86.40
    let costPerBox9m3 = 90.90
    let costPerBox13m3 = 111.57
    let costPerBox15m3 = 136.36
    let costPerKilometer = 0.77
    let costPerHour = 28.01
    let BTW: Double = 1.21
    
    func calculateDiscount() -> (Double, Double) {
        if selectedHuurTermijn >= 3 && selectedHuurTermijn <= 8 {
            return (5.0, 5.0)
        } else if selectedHuurTermijn >= 9 && selectedHuurTermijn <= 12 {
            return (10.0, 10.0)
        } else if selectedHuurTermijn >= 13 {
            return (15.0, 15.0)
        } else {
            return (0.0, 0.0)
        }
    }
    
    func calculateBoxCosts(boxCount: Int, boxCost: Double, discount: Double) -> Double {
        return Double(boxCount) * selectedHuurTermijn * (boxCost - discount)
    }
    
    func calculateCosts() {
        print(kilometersHeen)
        let selectedHuurTermijn = huurTermijnen[selectedHuurTermijnIndex]
        // Bereken opslagkosten
        storageCost = (Double(selectedBox9m3) * selectedHuurTermijn * RentcostPerBox) +
                      (Double(selectedBox13m3) * selectedHuurTermijn * RentcostPerBox) +
                      (Double(selectedBox15m3) * selectedHuurTermijn * RentcostPerBox)
        
        // Bereken kilometerkosten
        let totalKilometers = (Double(kilometersHeen) ) + (Double(kilometersTerug) )
        let totalBoxes = Double(selectedBox9m3 + selectedBox13m3 + selectedBox15m3)
        kilometerCost = (totalKilometers * 2 * costPerKilometer) * totalBoxes
        
        // Bereken tijdskosten
        let totalTimeHeen = Double(selectedTijdHeen) / 12.0 // omzetten naar uren
        let totalTimeTerug = Double(selectedTijdTerug) / 12.0
        let totalWachtTijdHeen = Double(selectedWachtTijdHeen) / 4.0
        let totalWachtTijdTerug = Double(selectedWachtTijdTerug) / 4.0
        let totalTime = (totalTimeHeen + totalTimeTerug) * 2 + totalWachtTijdHeen + totalWachtTijdTerug
        timeCost = totalTime * costPerHour * totalBoxes
        
        // Bereken TT Kosten
        let totalTTTimeHeen = Double(selectedTTTijdHeen) / 4.0
        let totalTTTimeTerug = Double(selectedTTTijdTerug) / 4.0
        totalCostTT = (totalTTTimeHeen + totalTTTimeTerug) * 50
        
        // Bereken totale kosten
        totalCost = storageCost + kilometerCost + timeCost + totalCostTT
    }
    
    func calculateOmzet() {
        let marginFactor = Double(geselecteerdeMarge) / 100.0
        let marginOmzet = 1.0 + marginFactor
        let totalBoxes = Double(selectedBox9m3 + selectedBox13m3 + selectedBox15m3)
        
        let (discount13m3, discount15m3) = calculateDiscount()
            huurOmzet = calculateBoxCosts(boxCount: selectedBox9m3, boxCost: costPerBox9m3, discount: 0) +
                        calculateBoxCosts(boxCount: selectedBox13m3, boxCost: costPerBox13m3, discount: discount13m3) +
                        calculateBoxCosts(boxCount: selectedBox15m3, boxCost: costPerBox15m3, discount: discount15m3)
        
        // Bereken tijdskosten
        let totalTimeHeen = Double(selectedTijdHeen) / 12.0 // omzetten naar uren
        let totalTimeTerug = Double(selectedTijdTerug) / 12.0
        let totalWachtTijdHeen = Double(selectedWachtTijdHeen) / 4.0
        let totalWachtTijdTerug = Double(selectedWachtTijdTerug) / 4.0
        let totalTime = (totalTimeHeen + totalTimeTerug) * 2 + totalWachtTijdHeen + totalWachtTijdTerug
        
        let timeCostHeen = (((totalTimeHeen * 2) + totalWachtTijdHeen) * costPerHour * totalBoxes) * marginOmzet
        let timeCostTerug = (((totalTimeTerug * 2) + totalWachtTijdTerug) * costPerHour * totalBoxes) * marginOmzet
        
        // Bereken kilometerkosten
        let transportkostenHeen = (((Double(kilometersHeen) * 2) * costPerKilometer) * totalBoxes) * marginOmzet
        
        let transportkostenTerug = (((Double(kilometersTerug) * 2) * costPerKilometer) * totalBoxes) * marginOmzet
        
        transportkostenHeenOmzet = transportkostenHeen + timeCostHeen
        
        transportkostenTerugOmzet = transportkostenTerug + timeCostTerug
        
        // Bereken TT Kosten
        let totalTTTimeHeen = Double(selectedTTTijdHeen) / 4.0
        let totalTTTimeTerug = Double(selectedTTTijdTerug) / 4.0
        
        ttOmzetHeen = totalTTTimeHeen * 66.12
        ttOmzetTerug = totalTTTimeTerug * 66.12
        
        totalOmzetEx = huurOmzet + transportkostenHeenOmzet + transportkostenTerugOmzet + ttOmzetHeen + ttOmzetTerug
        
        totalOmzetIncl = totalOmzetEx * 1.21
    }
    
    func resetValues() {
        selectedBox9m3 = 0
        selectedBox13m3 = 0
        selectedBox15m3 = 0
        selectedHuurTermijnIndex = 0
        kilometersHeen = 0
        kilometersTerug = 0
        selectedTijdHeen = 0
        selectedTijdTerug = 0
        selectedWachtTijdHeen = 0
        selectedWachtTijdTerug = 0
        selectedTTTijdHeen = 0
        selectedTTTijdTerug = 0
        totalCost = 0
    }
   
   // Genereer een lijst met tijden in stappen van 5 minuten van 00:00 tot 04:00
   let tijdsVerwachting = Array(stride(from: 0, to: 241, by: 5)).map {
       String(format: "%02d:%02d", $0 / 60, $0 % 60)
   }
   
   // Genereer een lijst met wachttijden in stappen van 15 minuten van 00:00 tot 04:00
   let wachtTijden = Array(stride(from: 0, to: 241, by: 15)).map {
       String(format: "%02d:%02d", $0 / 60, $0 % 60)
   }
    
    func calculateMarginData(marginPercent: Int) -> [Double] {
        let marginFactor = Double(marginPercent) / 100.0

        // Haal de kortingen op
        let (discount13m3, discount15m3) = calculateDiscount()
        
        // Bereken de andere variabelen
        let omzetInclMarge = ((kilometerCost + timeCost) * (1.0 + marginFactor)) + storageCost
        let ttTimeTotal = (Double(selectedTTTijdHeen) + Double(selectedTTTijdTerug)) / 4.0
        let omzetTtInclMarge = ttTimeTotal * 66.12
        
        // Gebruik de calculateBoxCosts() functie voor het berekenen van huuropbrengsten
        let huuropbrengsten =
            (selectedBox9m3 > 0 ? calculateBoxCosts(boxCount: selectedBox9m3, boxCost: costPerBox9m3, discount: 0.0) : 0.0) +
            (selectedBox13m3 > 0 ? calculateBoxCosts(boxCount: selectedBox13m3, boxCost: costPerBox13m3, discount: discount13m3) : 0.0) +
            (selectedBox15m3 > 0 ? calculateBoxCosts(boxCount: selectedBox15m3, boxCost: costPerBox15m3, discount: discount15m3) : 0.0)
        
        // Bereken de uiteindelijke variabelen
        let margeInEur = (omzetInclMarge + omzetTtInclMarge + huuropbrengsten) - totalCost
        let bedragExclBtw = (omzetInclMarge + omzetTtInclMarge + huuropbrengsten)
        let bedragInclBtw = bedragExclBtw * 1.21
        
        return [omzetInclMarge, omzetTtInclMarge, huuropbrengsten, margeInEur, bedragExclBtw, bedragInclBtw]
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Image("BOX Boxss Logo (RGB-wit)_def")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding(10)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 70, alignment: .trailing)
        .background(Color.init(hex: "D77D28"))
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        
        HStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Klant gegevens")
                    .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 25))
                
                Form {
                    // Aantal boxen
                    Picker("Aantal boxen 9 m3", selection: $selectedBox9m3) {
                        ForEach(0..<boxCounts.count) {
                            Text("\(self.boxCounts[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker("Aantal boxen 13 m3", selection: $selectedBox13m3) {
                        ForEach(0..<boxCounts.count) {
                            Text("\(self.boxCounts[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker("Aantal boxen 15 m3", selection: $selectedBox15m3) {
                        ForEach(0..<boxCounts.count) {
                            Text("\(self.boxCounts[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Verwachte huur termijn
                    Picker("Verwachte huur termijn", selection: $selectedHuurTermijnIndex) {
                        ForEach(0..<huurTermijnen.count) {
                            Text("\(self.huurTermijnen[$0], specifier: "%.1f")")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Kilometers
                    Picker("Kilometers heen", selection: $kilometersHeen) {
                        ForEach(kilometerCounts, id: \.self) { kilometer in
                            Text("\(kilometer)")
                                .tag(kilometer)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker("Kilometers Terug", selection: $kilometersTerug) {
                        ForEach(kilometerCounts, id: \.self) { kilometer in
                            Text("\(kilometer)")
                                .tag(kilometer)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Tijdsverwachting heen en terug
                    Picker("Tijdsverwachting heen", selection: $selectedTijdHeen) {
                        ForEach(0..<tijdsVerwachting.count) {
                            Text("\(self.tijdsVerwachting[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker("Tijdsverwachting terug", selection: $selectedTijdTerug) {
                        ForEach(0..<tijdsVerwachting.count) {
                            Text("\(self.tijdsVerwachting[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Wachttijd heen en terug
                    Picker("Verwachting wachttijd heen", selection: $selectedWachtTijdHeen) {
                        ForEach(0..<wachtTijden.count) {
                            Text("\(self.wachtTijden[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker("Verwachting wachttijd terug", selection: $selectedWachtTijdTerug) {
                        ForEach(0..<wachtTijden.count) {
                            Text("\(self.wachtTijden[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Form{
                    Picker("Uren TT heen p/box", selection: $selectedTTTijdHeen) {
                        ForEach(0..<wachtTijden.count) {
                            Text("\(self.wachtTijden[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker("Uren TT Terug p/box", selection: $selectedTTTijdTerug) {
                        ForEach(0..<wachtTijden.count) {
                            Text("\(self.wachtTijden[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                }
                        
                VStack {
                    Text("Kosten opslag box: €\(storageCost, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    Text("Kosten kilometers: €\(kilometerCost, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    Text("Kosten uren: €\(timeCost, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    Text("Kosten totaal: €\(totalCost, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    Text("Kosten TT: €\(totalCostTT, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    
                    Button("Reset totaal") {
                        resetValues()
                        calculateCosts()  // Update de kosten na het resetten van de waarden
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                }
                .padding(10)
                .onChange(of: selectedBox9m3, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
               .onChange(of: selectedBox13m3, perform: { value in
                   calculateCosts()
                   calculateOmzet()
               })
                .onChange(of: selectedBox15m3, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedHuurTermijnIndex, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: kilometersHeen, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: kilometersTerug, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedTijdHeen, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedTijdTerug, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedWachtTijdHeen, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedWachtTijdTerug, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedTTTijdHeen, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedTTTijdTerug, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
                .onChange(of: geselecteerdeMarge, perform: { value in
                    calculateCosts()
                    calculateOmzet()
                })
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 250, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            
            VStack{
                // Titel of Header als je wilt
                Text("Marge Berekeningen \(geselecteerdeMarge)%")
                    .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 25))

                // Definitie van de marge bereiken
                let margeRanges = [
                    Array(stride(from: 10, to: 56, by: 5)),
                    Array(stride(from: 60, to: 106, by: 5)),
                    Array(stride(from: 110, to: 291, by: 20)),
                    Array(stride(from: 300, to: 481, by: 20))
                ]

                ForEach(0..<margeRanges.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    let marges = Array(margeRanges[index])

                    HStack {
                        // Verticale Stack voor Labels
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Marge op kosten:")
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                                .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 17))
                            Text("Omzet incl marge:").frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                            Text("Omzet tt incl marge:")
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                            Text("Huuropbrengsten:")
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                            Text("Marge in €:")
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                                .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 15))
                            Text("Bedrag excl btw:")
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                            Text("Bedrag incl btw:")
                                .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 17))
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                        }

                        // Verticale Stack voor berekende waarden
                        ForEach(marges, id: \.self) { marge in
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                let result = calculateMarginData(marginPercent: marge)
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.geselecteerdeMarge = marge
                                }) {
                                    Text("\(marge)%")
                                        .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 17))
                                }
                                Text("\(result[0], specifier: "%.2f")").frame(width: 70, alignment: .center)
                                Text("\(result[1], specifier: "%.2f")").frame(width: 70, alignment: .center)
                                Text("\(result[2], specifier: "%.2f")").frame(width: 70, alignment: .center)
                                Text("\(result[3], specifier: "%.2f")")
                                                        .foregroundColor(result[3] < 0 ? Color.red : Color.green)
                                                        .frame(width: 70, alignment: .center)
                                                        .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 15))
                                Text("\(result[4], specifier: "%.2f")").frame(width: 70, alignment: .center)
                                Text("\(result[5], specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 17))
                                    .frame(width: 70, alignment: .center)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        // Titel of Header als je wilt
                        Text("Offerte Berekeningen")
                            .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Bold", size: 25))
                        
                        Text("Transportkosten heen: €\(transportkostenHeenOmzet, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        Text("Transportkosten terug: €\(transportkostenTerugOmzet, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        Text("Opslag huur: €\(huurOmzet, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        Text("Kosten tt heen: €\(ttOmzetHeen, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        Text("Kosten tt terug: €\(ttOmzetTerug, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        Text("excl btw: €\(totalOmzetEx, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        Text("incl btw: €\(totalOmzetIncl, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        
                        Button("Kopieer tekst") {
                            let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
                            pasteboard.clearContents()
                            pasteboard.setString("Transportkosten heen: €\(transportkostenHeenOmzet)\nTransportkosten terug: €\(transportkostenTerugOmzet)\n Opslag huur: €\(huurOmzet)\n Kosten tt heen: €\(ttOmzetHeen)\n Kosten tt terug: €\(ttOmzetTerug)\n excl btw: €\(totalOmzetEx)\n incl btw: €\(totalOmzetIncl)"
                                                 , forType: .string)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
       }
        .font(Font.custom("Rajdhani-Medium", size: 15))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I've tried to make the calculations happen only after pressing a button, but the app is still just as slow.

I've also shortened the code by creating various functions.

Additionally, I've tried to gather more information through ChatGPT, but it hasn't really provided suggestions for things I could do differently.

Comment: It looks like tapping a button executes some heavy calculations. Did you try to move them to a background thread (by means of async/await or Dispatch,) and update UI after the calculations are done?

Answer (score 1):

You have a single gigantic view containing hundreds (thousands?) of subviews. Every time any of your `@State` properties changes, SwiftUI has to examine every one of those subviews to see if it's changed.

You need to factor out subviews into their own types, and pass to them only the data they depend on. That way SwiftUI can reduce the number of views it needs to examine when some bit of data changes.

Watch [Apple's SwiftUI videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/all-videos/?q=swiftui). In particular, these might help:

- [Data Flow Through SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/)
- [Data Essentials In SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/)
- [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/)
- [Demystify SwiftUI Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10160/)